# Kubernetes worker node went down, what will happen to the pod?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I have setup a EKS in AWS, setup 2 worker node and configured the autosclaing on those nodes with 3 as desired capacity.
Sometime my worker node goes down due to "an EC2 health check indicating it has been terminated or stopped." which results my pod get restarted. I have not enabled any replicas for the pods. It is one now.

Just wanted to know, how can my services (pod) will be highly available despite of any worked node goes down or restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one pod for your service, then your service is NOT highly available. It is a single point of failure. If that pod dies or is restarted, as has happened here, then during the time the pod is being restarted, your service is dead.

You need a bare minimum, TWO pods for a service to be highly available, they they should be on different nodes (you can force Kuberentes to schedule the pods on different nodes using pod antiaffinity (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) so that if one node goes down as in your example, it takes out only pod, leaving the other pod(s) to handle the requests until the other pod can be rescheduled.